# How to define SQL Server Connection ID in airflow

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I am unable to create a SQL Server connection in Airflow.

This is the code I am using:

```
t2 = MsSqlOperator(
task_id='sql-op',
mssql_conn_id=ms_sql,
sql='SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
dag=dag)
```

defined my ms_sql in connections too.

In airflow UI connections;

```
Connection type:-Microsoft SQL Server
Host:-mssql+pymssql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PHONT536US
```

Getting this error:

> ERROR - Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

with same details able to connect in PYcharm in my local. but not in Airflow.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't put username, password and everything else in host field itself? Because there are separate fields in the UI for placing them. (if you are creating connection using CLI / programmatically, then your'e allowed to pass entire URI with all these details)

Comment: I tried by placing username and password  separately in UI,still I am getting the same error so I tried by placing the host like that ,but no improvement .

Comment: If you get this error while *creating connection in webUI*, the look into **`webserver`'s `logs` folder** for detailed error message. If you are getting this error upon *loading `DAG`s*, look into **`scheduler`'s logs folder**. If you get this error upon *running a DAG / operator*, look into **`worker`'s logs folder**. How are you running `Airflow`? By any chance, are you using [`puckel/docker-airflow`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)?

Comment: I created a connection ID in Airflow UI --> admin --> connections. When I'm running the dag in Airflow UI I can see the error in Logs .ERROR - Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason. I'm thinking that the error is because of connection details which I have mentioned in theAirflow UI --> admin --> connections.

Comment: I suggest you to `SSH` into your `worker` *node* and then launch a `python` *shell*. Then manually run the same steps that would be executed from within the `operator` (such as creating `MsSqlHook` using your `conn_id` & then using it to fire a query). That would likely let you diagnose the problem faster.

Comment: I tried with that too .still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: When I'm using Pyodbc in pycharm I can connect but when I tried in airflow ,not able to  connect.

Comment: Try to go through source code of `MsSqlHook` & `MsSqlOperator` (or whatever) and see if you can spot any inconsistency (in the way your'e using it). Last resort would be to put up your query on [gitter](https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow) or [dev-mailing-list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@airflow.apache.org)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Hook and operator connection in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954928/sql-server-hook-and-operator-connection-in-airflow)