# SQL Server Hook and operator connection in Airflow

Tags: sql-server, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am new to using airflow and what I need to do is to use `MssqlHook` or `MssqlOperator` but I do not know how.

By using hook and operator below code

```
hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id=ms_sql)

t2 = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id = 'sql-op',
        mssql_conn_id = ms_sql,
        sql = 'Select Current_date()',
        dag = dag)
```

in Airflow UI connections-

```
Conn Id - ms_sql
Conn Type -Microsoft SQL server
Host - host_name
schema- default
login- username
password- password
port - 14481
```

And when I do this the error is

> Connection failed for unknown reason

How should I connect?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859197/mssqlhook-airflow-connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MssqlHook airflow connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859197/mssqlhook-airflow-connection)

Comment: i tried with that but still facing the same issue